# css vertically resize and reposition scrollbar

Tags: css

I have an image with spacing on the top and the bottom, wrapped with a scrollable div like so:

```
<div class="scroller">
    ::before
    <img source="blah"></img>
    ::after
</div>
```

However, the scrollbar starts at the very top and ends at the very bottom.
My goal is to make the scrollbar start at the same height as the image when fully scrolled up, and stop at the end of the image.

The orange area represents the image.

What it looks like right now: [image: Original]

this is what I want it to look like: [image: Goal]

I tried wrapping the image in another div and making that the div that has the scrollbar, but that won't work, because then when you scroll up the image will not go above the scrollbar. These areas would not be visible anymore: [image]

Heres [a demo](http://codepen.io/L0laapk3/pen/YWYpLk?editors=1100)

PS It only needs to work in chrome if that makes it easier :)

edit: The following gif visualises why wrapping it is not an option, the top and bottom parts (marked in red on the third picture) would never be visible:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like This? : http://jsbin.com/puvonovafa/edit?html,css,output

```css
.header,
.footer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
div.content {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 10vh;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.footer {
  bottom: 0
}
div.scrollMe {
  height: 100vh;width:100vw;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="scrollMe">test </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have edited the question to show the last image as an image instead of as a link, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroller">
      <img class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scroller{
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image{
  height: 500px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ttaxofa3/2/

Comment: I have edited the question to show the last image as an image instead of as a link, I hope it is more clear now.